# I have set a discord bot on glitch.com website but it's actually not finding discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

The error is :

```
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'discord.js'
Require stack:
- /app/bot.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:610:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:526:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
at Object.<anonymous> (/app/bot.js:1:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:826:10)
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:613
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'discord.js'
Require stack:
- /app/bot.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:610:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:526:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
at Object.<anonymous> (/app/bot.js:1:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:826:10)
```

I don't know how to make it find discord.js.

Thank you for answers !

[Here are the files contained in the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9Arg.png)

Answer (score 0):

What about package? Did you added discord.js
from package.json?
if you don't know I'll try to explain : go to package.json and click to `add packages` and type `discord.js` to there. And click the first thing you see. I hope it works!

Comment: Well, it doesn't work and it tells me ```We're sorry, something went wrong! Please try again, or try refreshing the editor.```